# how to use startActivityForResult in Nativescript

Tags: android, nativescript, startactivityforresult

I use a 
[extended activity](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/advanced-topics/extend-application-activity#extending-activity) in my old project, and I want to use **[startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)** in the **public onCreate()** function.

However I don't know how to solve the error

```
System.err: Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Failed resolving method startActivityForResult on class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

the code was ok.

```
activity.startActivityForResult( intent, this.MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST );
```

the above code was in the **public onCreate()** function.

but when I upgraded all the npm packges, including updating android platform to v5.0.0 and android library to v28.

and update the code from

```
class MainActivity extends android.app.Activity {
```

to

```
class MainActivity extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity {
```

the old code just not work anymore.

```
System.err: Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Failed resolving method startActivityForResult on class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

I think maybe it's related to **startActivityForResult()**.

I'm new to nativescript and android.

**How do I use this function in my extended activity correctly?**

I want to get this answer.

But if there are other workarounds will be good, too.

For example, I tried to use old code back

```
class MainActivity extends android.app.Activity {
```

the above one, but not work.

```
System.err: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
System.err: Calling js method onViewAttachedToWindow failed
System.err: 
System.err: TypeError: this._context.getSupportFragmentManager is not a function
System.err: File: "file:///data/data/com.testapp/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view.js, line: 190, column: 46
System.err: 
System.err: StackTrace: 
System.err:   Frame: function:'View._getRootFragmentManager', file:'file:///data/data/com.testapp/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view.js', line: 190, column: 47
System.err:   Frame: function:'View._getFragmentManager', file:'file:///data/data/com.testapp/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view.js', line: 215, column: 32
System.err:   Frame: function:'Frame._processNextNavigationEntry', file:'file:///data/data/com.testapp/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 134, column: 28
System.err:   Frame: function:'Frame._onAttachedToWindow', file:'file:///data/data/com.testapp/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 118, column: 14
System.err:   Frame: function:'AttachListener.onViewAttachedToWindow', file:'file:///data/data/com.testapp/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 35, column: 27
System.err:
```

If there are any methods to make the code **startActivityForResult** work again will all be ok.

My AndroidManifest.xml contains

```
android:minSdkVersion="21"
android:targetSdkVersion="23"
```

Does that mean all the devices >= 21 will be accepted,

[android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity)

the doc shows **added in version 25.1.0**

will I need to update my **AndroidManifest.xml**, too?

---

#### update

the code is from https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/advanced-topics/extend-application-activity#extending-activity

using TYPESCRIPT

```
@JavaProxy("org.myApp.MainActivity")
class Activity extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity {
    private _callbacks: AndroidActivityCallbacks;
    public readonly MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 100;

    public onCreate(savedInstanceState: android.os.Bundle): void {
        if (!this._callbacks) {
            setActivityCallbacks(this);
        }

        this._callbacks.onCreate(this, savedInstanceState, super.onCreate);

        let intent: android.content.Intent = new android.content.Intent( ( <any> android.provider.Settings ).ACTION_HOME_SETTINGS );
        intent.setData( Uri.parse( "package:" + context.getPackageName() ) );
        let activity = app.android.foregroundActivity || app.android.startActivity;
        activity.startActivityForResult( intent, this.MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST );
    }
```

almost all the same, but add some code for **startActivityForResult**.

if removing the line **startActivityForResult**, everything works fine again.

---

#### update ###

same error when using **this**.startActivityForResult()

```
System.err: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err: 
System.err: Error: java.lang.Exception: Failed resolving method startActivityForResult on class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.resolveMethodOverload(Runtime.java:1075)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1116)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:996)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:983)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:967)
System.err:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:959)
System.err:     com.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
System.err:     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
System.err:     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
```

---

#### update

[my steps to creating the app](https://w10schools.com/posts/246374_NativeScript-android-activity-test)

[the code](https://github.com/hejefew/test)

Comment: post your complete code to check what is reason of error

Comment: looks like your target activity is using fragment activity.

Comment: ok, I added the steps and the code now.

Comment: Thank you for the last update. I could not find how to start an activity. I summed up the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58892418/open-an-android-native-settings-menu-page-programmatically-in-nativescript/58892419#58892419). Thanks for the test repo.

Answer (score 1):

`android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` extends from `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`.

so if you want to use AppCompatActivity, you should include both **v4 compat library** and **v7 compat library**.

Comment: I copied the code from https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/advanced-topics/extend-application-activity#extending-activity 
TYPESCRIPT

```
@JavaProxy("org.myApp.MainActivity")
class Activity extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity {
```

how do I import **android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity** here?

Answer (score 0):

I think due to recent changes in core modules, your activity variable will be undefined inside the create callback.

Try a timeout or use `this` instead, like

```
  this.startActivityForResult(intent, this.MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST );
```

Comment: same error **Error: java.lang.Exception: Failed resolving method startActivityForResult on class android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity** when using **this**

Comment: How to **Try a timeout**? I don't understand.

Comment: It suppose to be `AppCompatActivity`, do you have a repo with sample project, so we can take a quick look.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this. I posted about it here:

https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/7442

I managed to fix the issue moving away from using a variable, or at least, a class-scoped variable. I'm assuming in the transpilation between JavaScript and Java these are lost.

The changes, highlighted from that issue, are:

```js
this.startActivityForResult(intent, this.REQUEST_CODE_SET_DEFAULT_DIALER);
```

where `this.REQUEST_CODE_SET_DEFAULT_DIALER` is `123`

I now have this instead

```
this.startActivityForResult(intent, 123);
```

I noted you can use local variables (non-`this`) but using the variable on the class caused issues.