# Getting error after update NativeScript to 5.0.0

Tags: nativescript, updates, nativescript-angular

I am new to `NativeScript`. After I have updated `NativeScript` to `5.0.0`, When I create default project and run using `tns run android` command, It is giving me following error :

```
 System.err: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
System.err: Calling js method onViewAttachedToWindow failed
System.err: TypeError: this._context.getSupportFragmentManager is not a function
System.err: File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.DemoApp/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view.js, line: 190, column: 46
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'View._getRootFragmentManager', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.DemoApp/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view.js', line: 190, column: 47
System.err:     Frame: function:'View._getFragmentManager', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.DemoApp/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/core/view/view.js', line: 215, column: 32
System.err:     Frame: function:'Frame._processNextNavigationEntry', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.DemoApp/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 134, column: 28
System.err:     Frame: function:'Frame._onAttachedToWindow', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.DemoApp/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 118, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'AttachListener.onViewAttachedToWindow', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.DemoApp/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js', line: 35, column: 27
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1116)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:996)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:983)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:967)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:959)
System.err:     at com.tns.gen.java.lang.Object_frame_29_36_AttachListener.onViewAttachedToWindow(Object_frame_29_36_AttachListener.java:17)
System.err:     at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:13554)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2690)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2697)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2697)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2697)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1322)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1084)
System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5990)
System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
System.err:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
ActivityManager: Process org.nativescript.DemoApp (pid 22172) has died
```

Please help me with the answer. I am facing this issue since I have updated my `NativeScript` `Version`.

Comment: From which version you upgraded to 5.0? Did you follow the upgrade instructions?

Comment: I have upgraded `NativeScript` 4.2.3 to 5.0.0

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get answers for all my questions. Please let me know whether you followed the standard upgrade instructions, your runtime, core modules, angular and webpack config should be in sync with latest.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have something like

```
class MainActivity extends android.app.Activity {
```

I updated the Activity to AppCompatActivity for nativescript version 5

```
class Activity extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity {
```

and the error is gone.

but if you have `startActivityForResult`, maybe you will get other [new errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314046/how-to-use-startactivityforresult-in-nativescript) then.

Comment: No, I am having this issue in `NativeScript` not `AndroidStudio`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have upgraded just the NativeScript CLI and not the project's dependencies and runtime. Follow the detailed upgrade instruction in [this documentation section](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/releases/upgrade-instructions#upgrading-platforms) and make sure that you have migrated your entire project by updating the runtimes ('tns-android' and/or 'tns-ios'), the modules ('tns-core-modules') and all related plugins/dependencies.

Comment: I have followed same link and executed(upgraded) all commands(plugins). Still not working. Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. Actually I was having issue with `AndroidStudio`. By doing `ClearCache` in `AndroidStudio` my problem get solved. It might be space issue that `AndroidStudio` was occupying in disc so my `NativeScript` application was not getting enough space.