# Opening a native settings menu page programmatically in NativeScript

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, nativescript, settings

How can you programmatically open a page from the native Android settings menu using NativeScript?
Classic java examples show it can be done this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

but how to do the same in NativeScript?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the module `tns-core-modules/application`, which will make `startActivity` available. An example using TypeScript is provided below:

```js
import * as appM from 'tns-core-modules/application';

const intent = new android.content.Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
const activity = appM.android.foregroundActivity || appM.android.startActivity;
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Unfortunately, TypeScript types are not included for `foregroundActivity` and `startActivity`, which made finding a solution to this extremely hard.
A big thanks to [user10655801](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10655801/user10655801) for his test repo containing the solution.

Comment: Typings for native APIs is really huge and not every one may need it. So it's optional, you will have to install `tns-platform-declarations` plugin to use them.

Comment: @Manoj Indeed, I have the plugin `tns-platform-declarations` installed. What I meant is that both `foregroundActivity` and `startActivity` are defined as `any`, so it was really difficult to understand that `startActivityForResult` had to be called from them. I will edit the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Just to clarify, without the (optional) plugin in place it's not possible to define the type as Activity. Though the type is mentioned in the comments of the same declarations.

Comment: What do you mean with your first sentence? I said I do have the plugin installed and working, or are you referring to another plugin? I still do not get why types exists for `appM.android` but not for the methods of `appM.android.startActivity`.